# RazorPages: Model does not get instantiated in Partial with Page Model

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Im testing out RazorPages and .Net Core **2.1**

I have just taken a new project template and have created a Partial.
These are relevant/added contents of the files.

My problem is

1) Immediate problem: In the partial: OnGetAsync (nor public void OnGet()) does not get called. and I get a NullReference-exceptiion in View on Model on line

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ImageBE) {
```

I have tried to cut out DB-call and excplicitly call OnGet from contructor but no difference.

2) I cant to find an example where the Page(index) has an instance of the Partials model (ImageGalleryModel below). but this is the only thing the compiler will accept. Am I doing this totally wrong?

Index.cshtml (the page)

```
...
[partial name="_ImageGallery" model="Model.ImageGallery" /]
...
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        ApplicationDbContext mContext;
        public ImageGalleryModel ImageGallery;

        public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            mContext = context;
            ImageGallery = new ImageGalleryModel(mContext);
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
```

_ImageGallery.cshtml (the partial)

```
[table class="table"]
    @foreach (var item in Model.ImageBE) {
              ...
```

_ImageGallery.cshtml.cs

```
public class ImageGalleryModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public IList<ImageBE> ImageBE { get; set; }

        public ImageGalleryModel(Photiqo.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            ImageBE = await _context.ImageBE.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Partials should not have a PageModel file associated with them. If you have C# code that you want to execute, you should consider creating a [ViewComponent](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/view-components).

Alternatively, you can move the `public IList<ImageBE> ImageBE` property to the `IndexModel` and instantiate it in the `OnGetAsync` method there. Then you can specify the model type on the partial and pass it to the partial using the tag helper as you currently re doing:

_ImageGallery.cshtml (the partial)

```
@model IList<ImageBE>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for your reply! ok, fair enough. But I get the same result even if I dont inherit from PageModel (or follow your example literally). I know that this "should" work. Ive tried initiate the list in page's ctor, and On*Get(), on model's ctor, override the get-property with a hardcoded list. It always ends up as null in the view.

Comment: You are obviously missing something somewhere... perhaps you can review the section on strongly typed partials on this page: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages#strongly-type-partials to see if it lights a bulb for you.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I will start from scratch this evening after work. Thanks for the link and your help :)